# Is parent child hierarchy important on throws while overriding.?

Tags: java, oop, exception, polymorphism, overriding

Please find my code below, I want to clear my concept on overriding along with throws exceptions. Will below provided code work, if yes then why.? I'm asking this question because there is no direct parent child relation between IOException and ArithmeticException.

```
public class TestExceptionChild {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        try {
            parent.msg();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Parent{  
    void msg() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("parent");
    }  
}

class Child extends Parent{  
    void msg() throws ArithmeticException{
        System.out.println("child");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but only because `ArithmeticException` extends `RuntimeException` (i.e. it is not a checked exception, so the use of a `throws` clause here is unnecessary).  If instead of `ArithmeticException`, you use a checked exception, it must be or extend type `IOException`.  Otherwise, you will get a compile error.

So to answer your question, yes, hierarchy is important for *checked* exceptions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) for more details.

Comment: `IOException` isn't a `RuntimeException`, though. Why is the overriden method not required to also have `throws IOException`? How come it can throw *nothing*, but not throw another kind of checked exception?

Comment: @Gendarme You can think of "throws nothing" as a subset of `throws IOException`.  The inverse is not true, however.  If the parent throws nothing, the overridden child cannot throw a checked exception.

Comment: I would add that to the answer.

Comment: So does that mean hierarchy doesn't matter for a scenario where parent method its throwing checked exceptions and child throws unchecked exceptions..?

Comment: @RajBhatia `throws` is for checked exceptions.  Excluding documentation purposes, it is meaningless for unchecked exceptions.